# Ssd not recognised by bios

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, bios

I tried to install my samsung 970 evo plus from my old laptop into my pc but it doesn't show up on bios and windows. I reinstalled it into my laptop and it worked fine. My ssd is compatible with my motherboard but i plugged it in my brother's computer (it's the exact same) but it also isn't working.
My SSD has MBR partioning and both my laptop and pc are configured for UEFI mode.
Ssd is a samsung 970 evo plus 1tb nvme m.2.
Motherboard is ECS B560H6-EM.

Comment: Is the SSD partitioned MBR or GPT?  Is the laptop configured for CSM or UEFI mode?  Is the desktop configured for CSM or UEFI mode?  [Edit] your question to include this vital information.

Comment: What model is your PC? What motherboard connector did you use for the disk?

Comment: @Ramhound I edited it.

Comment: The question in the 2nd and 3rd comments are quite pertinent. Keep in mind that any M.2 drive fits any M.2 slot but the motherboard may not support one type or the other, SATA or NVMe. So, knowing exactly what the hardware is is crucial to understand the problem.

Comment: @ChanganAuto what do you mean exactly with hardware

Comment: I mean the exact SSD model to know whether it's SATA or NVMe and the motherboard's model to check whether or not it's compatible. It should be obvious.

Comment: @ChanganAuto i think i added all the hardware that is necessary.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Now, do you have one M.2 drive already installed don't you? And Intel RST enabled in UEFI? If so the 2nd drive won't be visible.

Comment: @ChanganAuto how do i make it visible then?

Comment: It depends on what usages you intend. You may add it to the Intel RST "RAID", use for "Intel Optane" (you'll have to google most of this, I'm not the person to answer confidently about something I don't use). But if you want to use as an independent drive then yes, you have to change to AHCI, and again, you need to install AHCI support in Windows before changing modes or it won't boot.

Comment: @ChanganAuto how do i install AHCI support?

Comment: Googling is not that difficult. This is one of the first results: https://support.thinkcritical.com/kb/articles/switch-windows-10-from-raid-ide-to-ahci